# Python write to a file

Tags: python, file, hash

I want to write the random generated hashes to a textfile, but everytime in the textfile is no text. What can I do?
Here is my code:

```
import hashlib
import string 
from random import randint 
import random
import time

rnd = randint(10,20)
while True:
    rndChar = ""
    for _ in range(rnd):
        rndChar += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
    md5out = hashlib.md5(rndChar).hexdigest()
    float.fromhex('0.' + md5out[:16])
    float.fromhex('0.' + md5out[:16])
    print md5out
    file = open('/home/testuser/Desktop/hash.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(md5out))
    file.close()
```

Console output looks like this:

```
2720df62db5dd1881b011198280eb993
283eafdd484385b4396c34df58936c85
91aeb7daf22c53531b3f56b6d640a948
784c7aaf8fe24148f4ffef7376951385
49557f13c14a3022dbaae67f39d5af5e
881a4744d9bbd996b2408fccff40f521
21ff71063f55c91051b609ad40d31d7c
```

So It works but not shown in the textfile on my Desktop. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it as `file = open('/home/testuser/Desktop/hash.txt', 'a')` as 'w' clears the text file each time.

heres the correct code
    import hashlib
    import string 
    from random import randint 
    import random
    import time

```
rnd = randint(10,20)
while True:
    rndChar = ""
    for _ in range(rnd):
        rndChar += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
    md5out = hashlib.md5(rndChar).hexdigest()
    float.fromhex('0.' + md5out[:16])
    float.fromhex('0.' + md5out[:16])
    print md5out
    file = open('/home/testuser/Desktop/hash.txt', 'a')
    file.write(str(md5out))
    file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks and how can I write each hash in a new line?

Comment: No problem - if you find it worked/helps please set it as an answer/upvote as it really helps - no idea how to write a comment on multiple lnes i am afraid

Answer (score 0):

put the opening of your file outside the while loop, as well as the closing. each time you open it it gets cleared.